# Qual a melhor forma de ler arrays aninhado dentro de um objeto?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
const [json, setJson] = useState({
    tags: [
      {
        key: "",
        value: ""
      }
    ],
    tagLists: [
      {
        name: "",
        values: [
          {
            fields: [
              {
                key: "",
                value: ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });
```

Suponto que eu precise criar um input text para cada index da propriedade "fields". Qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer isso? Eu acessei atrávés de 3 map(), um dentro do outro, da seguinte maneira:

```
json.tagLists.map((el) =>
  el.values.map((value) =>
    value.fields.map((_, index) => {
      return (...)
    }
  )
)
```

Esta solução funciona, porém, não acho que seria a mais correta.
Alguém saberia me dizer qual é a melhor forma de resolver isso?

Comment: Cara, acho que a grande questão seria como você vai utilizar esse json na sua aplicação, então não tem como dizer a melhor maneira de você fazer isso, vai depender. Eu faria uma boa separação desses useState em alguns componentes , e passar de parâmetro. Dessa forma que você esta fazendo, se você quiser alterar o `values` utilizando o `setJson`, você vai ter que utilizar o `setJson` para alterar o `value` dentro do `fields` dentro do `values` dentro da `tagLists`, fica meio complicado de acompanhar. Acho uma boa ver um exemplo no youtube de algo parecido com o que você quer e ir modificando.

Comment: De cara eu já separaria o useState em tags e tagLists, mas novamente, vai depender:

`const [tags , setTags ] = useState([...])`
`const [tagLists, setTagLists ] = useState([...])`

Comment: Eu estou usando o Json completo como estado inicial porque será da mesma forma que preciso enviar para o backend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Crie componentes para cada nível do seu array.
Exemplo:

```
<>
 <Tags tags={json.tags}/>
 <TagsList list={json.tagLists} />
</>
```

Seu TagsList:

```
<>
{props.list.map(tag=> <Tag tag={tag}/>)}
</>
```

Seu Tag:

```
<>
<label>{props.tag.name}</label>
<SubValues values={props.tag.values}/>
</>
```

E assim por diante, então você separa o código, a lógica e a responsabilidade.